# What is the Difference between Excel Value and Value2

Tags: excel, vba

What's the Difference between Value and Value2?

```
    Dim strTemp As String

    strTemp = ActiveSheet.Range("A1").Value

    strTemp = ActiveSheet.Range("A1").Value2
```

Answer (score 1):

- Value2 - is the actual numeric value
- Value - is the formatted value

from: https://bettersolutions.com/excel/cells-ranges/vba-value2.htm

If in a cell you enter 01-01-2017

Then value will return: `01-01-2017`

and value2 will return: `42736`

Answer (score 0):

The only difference between this property and the `Value` property is that the `Value2` property doesn’t use the `Currency` and `Date` data types. You can return values formatted with these data types as floating-point numbers by using the `Double` data type.